# How do you determine the original .NET language from the compiled assembly?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Is there a way to determine the language in which an assembly was originally written? I was considering looking at the referenced assemblies or something similar but wondered if it's as simple as a specific assembly attribute or such...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no specific attribute.  Just hints.  If you see an assembly reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic then the odds are high that it was written in VB.NET.  If you see a `<CppImplementationDetails>` class then it was written in C++/CLI.  Absence of these hints makes C# likely.  Ignoring the possibilities of a Mono assembly or the dozens of language ports to .NET

Comment: that confirms my suspicions; I was hoping for a nice, juicy (explicit) value somewhere.

Comment: Not caring about the language is rather a big deal in .NET, avoid having to ask the question.

Comment: VB.Net and C# both convert to IL, so they compile to the same language.

Comment: @jlafay: True, but they use a different compiler, so C# and VB.NET can for example handle embedded ressource's namespaces differently, so you absolutely have to differentiate in code (if you use embedded ressources and get them by name...), if your library is intended to be working for both... And there are a lot of other such tiny little "gems" ...